# Using isalpha and white space removal

Tags: c

Hello I am very new to C and had a simple question.

I made a function that takes in a string that is supposed to take out white-space and special characters , and convert all upper case letters to lower case.

But when it runs it only coverts the upper case to the lower case.

```
void txtedit(char *str){

int i;

for(i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) {

    if (isalpha(str[i])) {
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);

    }//end if
}//end for
}//end void function
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: How do you think it will "remove" the whitespaces?

Comment: You need another variable, say `int j = 0;` and then `str[j++] = tolower(str[i]);` Don't forget to write a new string terminator when you finish. This will keep just alphabet characters, a step nearer to your goal. If you want to keep alphabet and numeral, change `isalpha` to `isalnum`.

Comment: With the goal "take out white-space and special characters " from a string, be sure to leave a `'\0'` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the non-alphabetical characters and the spaces you could have a while loop at the beginning (under your for loop) that says something like

```
while (!((str[i]>='a'&& str[i]<='z') || (str[i]>='A'&& str[i]<='Z' || line[i]=='\0'))){
```

(that makes sure that the characters in the new string are a-z or A-Z and not a space),

and then create a variable called j to fill with the alphabetic characters:

```
        for(j=i;str[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            str[j]=str[j+1];
        }
        str[j]='\0';
    }
}
```

then print the string and hopefully that works. Let me know what happened!